# php mysql parse data to input sql query

Tags: php

Hi guys i have a small project that fetches data from telnet cmd reply and parses it in order to update on a mysqli table, atm i am having the following issue its not copying the data properly to the table, in fact its not updating.. below a real log from the telnet parse

> show ont info 1 all

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run      Config   Match     Desc
        ID                    flag      state    state    state
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0/0  1  1   80:14:A8:A6:B8:E2 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT-TA.
 0/0  1  2   80:14:A8:AA:45:80 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT-NA.
 0/0  1  3   80:14:A8:98:12:F0 active    online   success  match     EURIZAM-MO.
 0/0  1  4   E0:67:B3:A6:56:73 active    online   success  match     DOUGLAS-CA.
 0/0  1  5   C4:70:0B:26:B1:58 active    online   success  match     AFONSO-LEM.
 0/0  1  6   80:14:A8:32:0B:60 active    online   failed   match     ALINE-FERR.
 0/0  1  7   80:14:A8:A6:BB:13 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT-R..
 0/0  1  8   E0:E8:E6:4E:74:C0 active    online   success  match     MARCIA-CAR.
 0/0  1  9   80:14:A8:A6:54:1F active    offline  initial  initial   ONU-EXT-JE.
 0/0  1  10  E0:67:B3:7E:03:CA active    online   success  match     MARIA-AGUI
```

.

```
 0/0  1  11  C4:70:0B:26:B2:E0 active    online   success  match     CRISTINO-A.
 0/0  1  12  44:55:B1:07:7E:11 active    online   success  match     IRACEMA-SI.
 0/0  1  13  80:14:A8:AA:6D:F0 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT
 0/0  1  14  E0:E8:E6:4E:55:10 active    online   success  match     LENILDE-OL.
 0/0  1  15  E0:67:B3:B2:FC:8F active    online   success  match     VINICIUS-N.
```

the following code below filters and removes the security escape strings..

and tries to filter the data to load on the sql query

> ```
> $show_pon[15] = "show ont info 16 all";
> ```

```
 $debug = true;
    // debug testing purposes
    if ($debug) {
        $cache = '/tmp/onu_data_auth-info.log';
        $contents = @file_get_contents($cache);
        if ($contents == false) 
        {
            $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $poninfo_resposta);
            file_put_contents($cache, $poninfo_resposta);
        } else 
        {
            $poninfo_resposta = $contents;
        }
    } else 
    {
        $telnet->DoCommand($show_pon, $poninfo_resposta);// estatisticas resposta.. coloca no array o dump resposta
    }
     $poninfo_resposta = preg_split('/\r?\n/', trim($poninfo_resposta));
     //die(print_r($poninfo_resposta, true)); 
     
      $headers = ['  F/S ' => 0, 'P' => 0, 'ONT ID' => 0, 'MAC' => 0, 'Control flag' => 0, 'Run state' => 0, 'Config state' => 0, 'Match state' => 0, 'Desc' => 0];
     
    $pdo_dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
    $pdo_dbh->query('select 1') or die('ping  fail');
    
     foreach ($poninfo_resposta as $row) 
    {
         
        
        if (stripos($row, 'F/S') !== false && stripos($row, 'Match state') !== false) 
        {
            foreach ($headers as $header => $idx) {
                $headers[$header] = stripos($row, $header);
            }

            continue;
        }

        $fields1 = array_fill(0, 9, '');            
    
        if (stripos($row, '0/0') !== false) 
        {
            $row = trim(str_replace('', '', $row));
            
            reset($headers);
            $i = 0;
            do 
            {
                $current = current($headers);
                $next = next($headers);
                
                if ($next !== false) 
                {                   
                $payload = substr($row, $current, $next - $current);  
                } 
                else 
                {
                $payload = substr($row, $current);                    
                }
                prev($headers);
                $fields1[$i++] = $payload;                              
            } 
            while(next($headers) !== false);
            $query = "INSERT INTO ont_onu (frame_slot, pon, ont_id, mac_address, control_flag, run_state, config_state, match_state, description)) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     
            $sth = $pdo_dbh->prepare( $query );
            if (!$sth) {
                die('fail preparing query');
            }               
            
            die(print_r($fields1, true));
            if (!$sth->execute($fields1)) {
                var_dump($sth->errorInfo());
                die('fail executing query');
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the output, reply which is not forwarded to the mysql, because the headers somewhow do not match

> ```
>  Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => 0/0 1 1 80:14:A8:A6:B8:E2 active online success match ONU-EXT-TA. )
> ```

as we can see its not recognizing the data on the correct arrays in order to get update on the mysql tables  as it should be filtered correclty as below

> ```
>  Array ( [0] => 0/0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 80:14:A8:A6:B8:E2 [4] => active [5] => online [6] => success [7] => match [8] => ONU-EXT-TA. )
> ```

any ideas on how to do it correctly i am lost

Comment: First off, completely ignore the database. Your first task should be parsing the telnet output, the database should come later. Second, since we don’t have access to your telnet, we need sample data. Assuming what you’ve provided is accurate, the [headers are never found](https://3v4l.org/3Ktgo). Once that is corrected, you should probably [create a flag](https://3v4l.org/HTIF9) so that you don’t keep reparsing the headers.

Comment: Hi ok, yes the log output in the begining is accurate the exact same output from the telnet prompt

Comment: i am using the same code on another device and it works it, filters the headers correctly, but on this device as we can see on the original log, it looks like the headers are split in 2 lines, therefore its not matching the exact header thats why its not filtering it.

Comment: It is almost definitely related to your telnet settings themselves, something related to window size or an equivalent. However, whatever command you are running, I'd see if you can get delimited output (CSV, TSV, etc.) instead of columnular, which is only really intended for visual rendering, really.

Comment: i can get debug log and output to .txt file.. attached below log

Answer (score 0):

hi guys attached full txt.log debuged from device telnet reply

> 

```
OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 4 all 
Error: There is no ONT available.


OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 5 all 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run      Config   Match     Desc
          ID                    flag      state    state    state
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0/0  5  1   C4:70:0B:26:B9:08 active    online   success  match     DEIVID-SAN.
 0/0  5  2   E0:67:B3:A6:45:D3 active    online   success  match     LILMAR-ALV.
 0/0  5  3   54:4B:90:04:C4:43 active    online   failed   match     ONU-EXT-ES.
 0/0  5  4   24:FD:0D:C4:C7:3E active    online   success  match     MARIA-MORA.
 0/0  5  5   E0:67:B3:93:D7:0B active    online   success  match     EDNA-SILVA
 0/0  5  6   C4:70:0B:26:8A:20 active    online   success  match     FLAVIA-BAR.
 0/0  5  7   E0:67:B3:88:33:F1 active    online   success  match     ESCOLA-SÃƒ.
 0/0  5  8   E0:67:B3:88:3C:EE active    online   success  match     FABIO-SILV.
 0/0  5  9   E0:67:B3:88:1B:58 active    online   success  match     WYLLDON-BR.
 0/0  5  10  E0:67:B3:93:D6:F5 active    online   success  match     ALESSANDRO    
                                  
 .
 0/0  5  11  E0:E8:E6:4E:75:B0 active    online   success  match     DANILLO-SI.
 0/0  5  12  C4:70:0B:26:B3:40 active    online   success  match     RESTAURANT.
 0/0  5  13  54:4B:90:04:A7:51 active    online   failed   match     LUCIANO-AN.
 0/0  5  14  80:14:A8:A6:BE:EA active    online   success  match     ONUEXT-R.D.
 0/0  5  15  80:14:A8:A6:C4:2E active    online   success  match     ONUEXT-ZIL.
 0/0  5  16  80:07:1B:09:C8:88 active    online   success  match     OLIVIA-LIM.
 0/0  5  17  E0:67:B3:7E:03:B5 active    online   success  match     ALESSANDRA.
 0/0  5  18  E0:67:B3:93:F8:CD active    online   success  match     PAULO-BATI.
 0/0  5  19  E0:67:B3:A6:4D:83 active    online   success  match     ZILMA-CUNH.
 0/0  5  20  E0:E8:E6:4E:62:A0 active    online   success  match     ESTER-SOUZ.
 0/0  5  21  E0:67:B3:A6:58:11 active    online   success  match     MARINA-SIL.
 0/0  5  22  80:14:A8:AA:6E:38 active    online   success  match     ONU-CHACSE
    
 .
 0/0  5  23  C4:70:0B:26:B8:48 active    online   success  match     MARLENE-SA.
 0/0  5  24  E0:E8:E6:4E:75:F0 active    online   success  match     RONY-CESAR
 0/0  5  25  E0:67:B3:88:1D:53 active    online   success  match     KEYCE-SILV.
 0/0  5  26  80:14:A8:A6:B8:E3 active    online   success  match     ONU.EXT-GE.
 0/0  5  27  80:07:1B:09:CB:00 active    online   success  match     WELLINGTON.
 0/0  5  28  80:14:A8:AA:6D:B8 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT
 0/0  5  29  E0:67:B3:7E:0C:58 active    online   success  match     PAULO-BATI.
 0/0  5  30  70:A8:E3:81:DD:E6 active    online   success  match     MARIA-SILV.
 0/0  5  31  C4:70:0B:26:95:B0 active    online   success  match     SHIRLEY-FE.
 0/0  5  32  C4:70:0B:26:51:98 active    online   success  match     JOAO-NETO
 0/0  5  33  80:14:A8:96:FF:58 active    online   success  match     BRUNO-LUZ
 0/0  5  34  E0:E8:E6:8D:B9:E9 active    online   success  match     ACASSIO-OL.
 0/0  5  35  E0:E8:E6:4E:6C:E0 active    online   success  match     JANAINA-KI. 
                                  
   
 0/0  5  36  C4:70:0B:26:C2:68 active    online   success  match     MARILVA-LI.
 0/0  5  37  E0:E8:E6:4E:62:88 active    online   success  match     JOAO-SORVE.
 0/0  5  38  E0:67:B3:88:29:D1 active    online   success  match     EDIMILSON-.
 0/0  5  42  E0:67:B3:7E:03:F1 active    online   success  match     ONU-ESCRIT.
 0/0  5  43  E0:67:B3:88:33:8B active    online   success  match     SAMUEL-PAU.
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total: 40, online 40

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 9 all
```

This is the full ouput result on the terminal window from the device telnet

below log without being parsed

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 4 all
Error: There is no ONT available.

### OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 5 all

### F/S  P  ONT MAC               Control   Run      Config   Match     Desc
ID                    flag      state    state    state

### 0/0  5  1   C4:70:0B:26:B9:08 active    online   success  match     DEIVID-SAN.
0/0  5  2   E0:67:B3:A6:45:D3 active    online   success  match     LILMAR-ALV.
0/0  5  3   54:4B:90:04:C4:43 active    online   failed   match     ONU-EXT-ES.
0/0  5  4   24:FD:0D:C4:C7:3E active    online   success  match     MARIA-MORA.
0/0  5  5   E0:67:B3:93:D7:0B active    online   success  match     EDNA-SILVA
0/0  5  6   C4:70:0B:26:8A:20 active    online   success  match     FLAVIA-BAR.
0/0  5  7   E0:67:B3:88:33:F1 active    online   success  match     ESCOLA-SÃƒ.
0/0  5  8   E0:67:B3:88:3C:EE active    online   success  match     FABIO-SILV.
0/0  5  9   E0:67:B3:88:1B:58 active    online   success  match     WYLLDON-BR.
0/0  5  10  E0:67:B3:93:D6:F5 active    online   success  match     ALESSANDRO                                     .
0/0  5  11  E0:E8:E6:4E:75:B0 active    online   success  match     DANILLO-SI.
0/0  5  12  C4:70:0B:26:B3:40 active    online   success  match     RESTAURANT.
0/0  5  13  54:4B:90:04:A7:51 active    online   failed   match     LUCIANO-AN.
0/0  5  14  80:14:A8:A6:BE:EA active    online   success  match     ONUEXT-R.D.
0/0  5  15  80:14:A8:A6:C4:2E active    online   success  match     ONUEXT-ZIL.
0/0  5  16  80:07:1B:09:C8:88 active    online   success  match     OLIVIA-LIM.
0/0  5  17  E0:67:B3:7E:03:B5 active    online   success  match     ALESSANDRA.
0/0  5  18  E0:67:B3:93:F8:CD active    online   success  match     PAULO-BATI.
0/0  5  19  E0:67:B3:A6:4D:83 active    online   success  match     ZILMA-CUNH.
0/0  5  20  E0:E8:E6:4E:62:A0 active    online   success  match     ESTER-SOUZ.
0/0  5  21  E0:67:B3:A6:58:11 active    online   success  match     MARINA-SIL.
0/0  5  22  80:14:A8:AA:6E:38 active    online   success  match     ONU-CHACSE                                     .
0/0  5  23  C4:70:0B:26:B8:48 active    online   success  match     MARLENE-SA.
0/0  5  24  E0:E8:E6:4E:75:F0 active    online   success  match     RONY-CESAR
0/0  5  25  E0:67:B3:88:1D:53 active    online   success  match     KEYCE-SILV.
0/0  5  26  80:14:A8:A6:B8:E3 active    online   success  match     ONU.EXT-GE.
0/0  5  27  80:07:1B:09:CB:00 active    online   success  match     WELLINGTON.
0/0  5  28  80:14:A8:AA:6D:B8 active    online   success  match     ONU-EXT
0/0  5  29  E0:67:B3:7E:0C:58 active    online   success  match     PAULO-BATI.
0/0  5  30  70:A8:E3:81:DD:E6 active    online   success  match     MARIA-SILV.
0/0  5  31  C4:70:0B:26:95:B0 active    online   success  match     SHIRLEY-FE.
0/0  5  32  C4:70:0B:26:51:98 active    online   success  match     JOAO-NETO
0/0  5  33  80:14:A8:96:FF:58 active    online   success  match     BRUNO-LUZ
0/0  5  34  E0:E8:E6:8D:B9:E9 active    online   success  match     ACASSIO-OL.
0/0  5  35  E0:E8:E6:4E:6C:E0 active    online   success  match     JANAINA-KI.
0/0  5  36  C4:70:0B:26:C2:68 active    online   success  match     MARILVA-LI.
0/0  5  37  E0:E8:E6:4E:62:88 active    online   success  match     JOAO-SORVE.
0/0  5  38  E0:67:B3:88:29:D1 active    online   success  match     EDIMILSON-.
0/0  5  42  E0:67:B3:7E:03:F1 active    online   success  match     ONU-ESCRIT.
0/0  5  43  E0:67:B3:88:33:8B active    online   success  match     SAMUEL-PAU.

Total: 40, online 40

OLT(config-interface-epon-0/0)# show ont info 9 all